# How to sort LiveData from Room Database? Doing a button to switch recyclerview's item's order

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-database

> Hello, I have two problems which I can't solve at all, but which I think are ultimately related.
>   I am triyng to do the following:
>   I have an activity (Nota) which serves as an add/edit note java class. I want to display these notes in the recyclerview in the ListFragment. And this I can do. However, when I tried to complicate things a bit more, I arrived at a dead end. For one, I want to sort the items according to 2 parameters, primarily by location and then by number of stars (in the rating bar), when the location is the same. Secondly, I also want to have a toggle button whose job is to switch these parameters, meaning firstly to filter according to the number of stars, and then according to the location. Any help would be appreciated.
>
> Now, moving on to what I have tried. The repository fetches the data using LiveData, which I can't seem to use for comparisons. So, I have tried to transform this to a list, I have tried to use MediatorLiveData and many other ways. Either way, I am still stuck pretty much where I started. So, this is my code:
>
> NoteDao

```
public interface NoteDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Notev2 note);

    @Update
    void update(Notev2 note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Notev2 note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT note_table.*, counter.count FROM note_table LEFT JOIN (SELECT note_table.location, count(note_table.location) as count FROM note_table GROUP BY note_table.location) counter ON counter.location = note_table.location ORDER BY counter.count DESC")
    LiveData<List<Notev2>> getAllNotes();
}
```

> This is my ListFragment

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int ADD_NOTE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST = 2;
    private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;

    private ListViewModel listViewModel;
    RecyclerView recyclerView_1;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_list);
        listViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });


        recyclerView_1 = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list_1);
        recyclerView_1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView_1.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final NoteAdapter nadapter = new NoteAdapter();
        recyclerView_1.setAdapter(nadapter);

        noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Notev2>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Notev2> notev2s) {
                nadapter.submitList(notev2s);
            }
        });

        nadapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Notev2 note) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Nota.class);
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_ID, note.getId());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_TITLE, note.getTitle_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_LOCATION, note.getLocation_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_STARS, note.getStars_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_1, note.getOpening_hours_1_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_2, note.getOpening_hours_2_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_3, note.getOpening_hours_3_v2());
                intent.putExtra(Nota.EXTRA_NOTAS, note.getNotas_v2());

                startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        final ToggleButton swap = (ToggleButton) root.findViewById(R.id.toggle_stars_location);
        swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (swap.isChecked()) {
                    swap.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                    swap.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.iswap_v2);
                    //noteViewModel.sortByStars();
                    nadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button_add_nota = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_nota);

        button_add_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Nota.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_NOTE_REQUEST);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ADD_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            String title = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_TITLE);
            String location = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            String stars = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_STARS);
            String open_1 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_1);
            String open_2 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_2);
            String open_3 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_3);
            String notas = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_NOTAS);

            Notev2 note = new Notev2(title, location, stars, open_1, open_2, open_3, notas);
            noteViewModel.insert(note);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (requestCode == EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            int id = data.getIntExtra(Nota.EXTRA_ID, -1);

            if (id == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note can't be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String title = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_TITLE);
            String location = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            String stars = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_STARS);
            String open_1 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_1);
            String open_2 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_2);
            String open_3 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_3);
            String notas = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_NOTAS);

            Notev2 note = new Notev2(title, location, stars, open_1, open_2, open_3, notas);
            note.setId(id);
            noteViewModel.update(note);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  else if (requestCode == EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK +10) {
            int id = data.getIntExtra(Nota.EXTRA_ID, -1);
            String title = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_TITLE);
            String location = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            String stars = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_STARS);
            String open_1 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_1);
            String open_2 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_2);
            String open_3 = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_OPEN_3);
            String notas = data.getStringExtra(Nota.EXTRA_NOTAS);
            Notev2 note = new Notev2(title, location, stars, open_1, open_2, open_3, notas);
            note.setId(id);
            noteViewModel.delete(note);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

> This is my Nota Activity (which I use to add/edit notes)

```
button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
        button_save.setEnabled(true);
        button_save.setClickable(true);
        button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveNote();
            }
        });

        EditText edit_new_sight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_sight);
        TextView opened_1 = findViewById(R.id.text_opened_1);
        TextView opened_2 = findViewById(R.id.text_opened_2);
        TextView opened_3 = findViewById(R.id.text_opened_3);
        RatingBar priority_bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.priority_stars);

        if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)) {
            delete_nota.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            toolbar_text.setText("Edit Sight");
            edit_new_sight.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
            String slocation = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION);
            if (slocation.contains("zioiu"))
                slocation = "";
            editLocation.setText(slocation);
            priority_bar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STARS)));
            opened_1.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_1));
            opened_2.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_2));
            opened_3.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_3));
            notas.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NOTAS));

        } else {
            toolbar_text.setText("New Sight");
        }

        delete_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });

    }
    private void saveNote() {

        EditText noteTitlep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_sight);
        EditText noteLocationp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_location);
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.priority_stars);
        String noteStars = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
        String noteTitle = (String) "" + noteTitlep.getText();
        if (noteTitle.equals("")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Nota.this, "Sorry, you need to input new sight!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } else if (noteStars.equals("0.0")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Nota.this, "Sorry, you need to input stars!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            TextView noteOpen_1p = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_opened_1);
            TextView noteOpen_2p = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_opened_2);
            TextView noteOpen_3p = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_opened_3);
            EditText noteNotasp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_notes);
            String noteLocation = (String) "" + noteLocationp.getText();
            String noteOpen_1 = (String) "" + noteOpen_1p.getText();
            String noteOpen_2 = (String) "" + noteOpen_2p.getText();
            String noteOpen_3 = (String) "" + noteOpen_3p.getText();
            String noteNotas = (String) "" + noteNotasp.getText();
            if (noteLocation.equals("")) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                noteLocation = "zioiu" + currentDateandTime;
            }
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, noteTitle);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, noteLocation);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_STARS, noteStars);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_1, noteOpen_1);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_2, noteOpen_2);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_OPEN_3, noteOpen_3);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTAS, noteNotas);
            int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
            if (id != -1) {
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            Toast.makeText(Nota.this, "Sight Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
```

> This is my NoteDatabase(v2)

```
public abstract class NoteDatabase_v2 extends RoomDatabase {
    private static NoteDatabase_v2 instance;

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

    public static synchronized NoteDatabase_v2 getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    NoteDatabase_v2.class, "note_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAllTables() {

    }

    private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private PopulateDbAsyncTask(NoteDatabase_v2 db) {
            noteDao = db.noteDao();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            noteDao.insert(new Notev2("Title 1", "Location 1", "1", "Open_1_1", "Open_2_1", "Open_3_1", "Notas_1"));
            noteDao.insert(new Notev2("Title 2", "Location 2", "2", "Open_1_2", "Open_2_2", "Open_3_2", "Notas_2"));
            noteDao.insert(new Notev2("Title 3", "Location 3", "3", "Open_1_3", "Open_2_3", "Open_3_3", "Notas_3"));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

> Sorry about so many javas, but there's still more
>   This is my NoteRepository

```
    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private LiveData<List<Notev2>> allNotes;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<Notev2>> medallnotes;

    public NoteRepository(Application application) {
        NoteDatabase_v2 database = NoteDatabase_v2.getInstance(application);
        noteDao = database.noteDao();
        allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Notev2 note) {
        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void update(Notev2 note) {
        new UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void delete(Notev2 note) {
        new DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
    }

    public void deleteAllNotes() {
        new DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute();
    }

    public MediatorLiveData<List<Notev2>> getAllNotes() {
        return (MediatorLiveData<List<Notev2>>) allNotes;
    }

    private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Notev2, Void, Void> {
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Notev2... notes) {
            noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Notev2, Void, Void> {
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private UpdateNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Notev2... notes) {
            noteDao.update(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Notev2, Void, Void> {
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private DeleteNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Notev2... notes) {
            noteDao.delete(notes[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private NoteDao noteDao;

        private DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            noteDao.deleteAllNotes();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> This is my Note(v2)

```
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    protected int id;
    String title;
    String location;
    String stars;
    String opening_hours_1;
    String opening_hours_2;
    String opening_hours_3;
    String notas;

    public Notev2(String title, String location, String stars, String opening_hours_1, String opening_hours_2,
                  String opening_hours_3, String notas) {
        this.title = title;
        this.location = location;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.opening_hours_1 = opening_hours_1;
        this.opening_hours_2 = opening_hours_2;
        this.opening_hours_3 = opening_hours_3;
        this.notas = notas;


    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle_v2() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLocation_v2() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getStars_v2() {
        return stars;
    }

    public String getOpening_hours_1_v2() {
        return opening_hours_1;
    }

    public String getOpening_hours_2_v2() {
        return opening_hours_2;
    }

    public String getOpening_hours_3_v2() {
        return opening_hours_3;
    }

    public String getNotas_v2() {
        return notas;
    }


}
```

> This is my NoteViewModel

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private NoteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Notev2>> allNotes;

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Notev2 note) {
        repository.insert(note);
    }

    public void update(Notev2 note) {
        repository.update(note);
    }

    public void delete(Notev2 note) {
        repository.delete(note);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Notev2>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    public void sortByStars() {
        Collections.sort((List<Notev2>) allNotes, ByStars);
    }
    public Comparator<Notev2> ByStars = new Comparator<Notev2>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Notev2 o1, Notev2 o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.stars).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.stars));
        }
    };
}
```

> And finally, this is my NoteAdapter

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ListAdapter<Notev2, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public NoteAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Notev2> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Notev2>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(Notev2 oldItem, Notev2 newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Notev2 oldItem, Notev2 newItem) {
            return oldItem.getTitle_v2().equals(newItem.getTitle_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getLocation_v2().equals(newItem.getLocation_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getStars_v2().equals(newItem.getStars_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getOpening_hours_1_v2().equals(newItem.getOpening_hours_1_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getOpening_hours_2_v2().equals(newItem.getOpening_hours_2_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getOpening_hours_3_v2().equals(newItem.getOpening_hours_3_v2()) &&
                    oldItem.getNotas_v2().equals(newItem.getNotas_v2());
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_list_1, parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position) {
        Notev2 currentNote = getItem(position);
        holder.nTitle.setText(currentNote.getTitle_v2());
        String slocation = "" + currentNote.getLocation_v2();
        if (slocation.contains("zioiu"))
            slocation = "";
        holder.nLocation.setText(slocation);
        Float numStars = Float.parseFloat(currentNote.getStars_v2());
        holder.nStars.setRating(numStars);
        holder.nOpen.setText(new StringBuilder().append(currentNote.getOpening_hours_1_v2()).append(currentNote.getOpening_hours_2_v2()).append(currentNote.getOpening_hours_3_v2()).toString());
        holder.nNotas.setText(currentNote.getNotas_v2());
    }

    public Notev2 getNoteAt(int position) {
        return getItem(position);
    }


    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nTitle,nLocation,nOpen,nNotas;
        RatingBar nStars;

        public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
            nLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_location);
            nStars = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_priority);
            nOpen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_openinghours);
            nNotas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_notas);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (listener != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getItem(position));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Notev2 note);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

> Thank you very much if you managed to read it this far.
>   All help is welcome.

Comment: Store the parameter that describes the sort order in a `MutableLiveData`, and use `Transformations.switchMap(sortOrder, (order) -> dao.findNotesByOrder(order))` to channel changes of the selected sort order into a SQLite query exposed through the DAO, so that you can use SQLite to order your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After much investigation, I finally arrived at an answer to my question. The key is to create new dao queries to filter the information, according to what you need.
>   This is my update NoteDao

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Notev2 note);

    @Update
    void update(Notev2 note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Notev2 note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT note_table.*, counter.count FROM note_table LEFT JOIN (SELECT note_table.location, count(note_table.location) as count FROM note_table GROUP BY note_table.location) counter ON counter.location = note_table.location ORDER BY counter.count DESC, stars DESC")
    LiveData<List<Notev2>> getAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT note_table.*, counter.count FROM note_table LEFT JOIN (SELECT note_table.location, count(note_table.location) as count FROM note_table GROUP BY note_table.location) counter ON counter.location = note_table.location ORDER BY stars DESC, counter.count DESC")
    LiveData<List<Notev2>> getAllNotesStars();

    //@Query("SELECT location, count(location) FROM note_table GROUP BY location ORDER BY count(location) DESC ")
    //LiveData<List<String>> getAllLocations();
}
```

Comment: How did you implement the database queries? I use a observerable for one list in my viewModel, but it does not observer these changes, I guess because the data set does not change, just the order. Do you use different lists in you viewModel to put the queried data in?

Answer (score 0):

Observer watches only to the LiveData's sourse, not to the field value. We need to switch liveData sourse

ListFragment

```
ViewModel.YOUR_VALUE.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ list ->
            list.let {
                YOUR_ADAPTER.submitList(it)
            }
     }

YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener {

    ViewModel.sortByYOU_FUNCTION()

   }
```

ViewModel file

```
val _YOUR_VALUE: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy{MutableLiveData(false)}

    val YOUR_VALUE =_YOUR_VALUE.switchMap { _allAnimals ->
        when(_allAnimals){
            true -> repository.SORTBY_YOURTH.asLiveData()
            else -> repository.SORTBY_YOURTH.asLiveData()
        }
    }
fun sortByYOU_FUNCTION(){
        _YOUR_VALUE.value = false
    }
```